# Mysqli to PHP to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

I'm not skilled with php and I'm only using it to proxy requests through a mysql database.  I have looked high and low for this but I can't figure out how to nest my json array, as I intend.

PHP

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{

    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {

    array_push($resultArray, $row); 
    }    

    echo json_encode($resultArray);

}
```

In my DB I have mappings for 'blocks' that can be associated with one another. PA_250x500_block,PA_250x500_TBlock & PA_250x500_StraightBlock.  All blocks can be designated a root or a branch.

JSON output

```
[
   {
      "root_class_name":"PA_250x500_block",
      "branch_class_name":"PA_250x500_Tblock"
   },
   {
      "root_class_name":"PA_250x500_block",
      "branch_class_name":"PA_250x500_StraightBlock"
   },
   {
      "root_class_name":"PA_250x500_StraightBlock",
      "branch_class_name":"PA_250x500_block"
   },
   {
      "root_class_name":"PA_250x500_StraightBlock",
      "branch_class_name":"PA_250x500_Tblock"
   },
   {
      "root_class_name":"PA_250x500_Tblock",
      "branch_class_name":"PA_250x500_StraightBlock"
   },
   {
      "root_class_name":"PA_250x500_Tblock",
      "branch_class_name":"PA_250x500_block"
   }
]
```

Instead of this output, i'm trying to get it nested more neatly as an array of compatible matches, not every possible combination:

```
   [
   {
      "root_class_name":"PA_250x500_Tblock",
      "branch_class_name":[
         "PA_250x500_StraightBlock",
         "PA_250x500_block"
      ]
   },
   {
      "root_class_name":"PA_250x500_Straightblock",
      "branch_class_name":[
         "PA_250x500_block",
         "PA_250x500_TBlock"
      ]
   },
   {
      "root_class_name":"PA_250x500_block",
      "branch_class_name":[
         "PA_250x500_StraightBlock",
         "PA_250x500_TBlock"
      ]
   }
]
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to turn this into a nested array with branch_class_name as a 1 to N list instead of being 1 to 1 objects?

Thanks,

Comment: What does your SQL query look like? (`$sql`) What does your database content and schema look like?

Comment: MySQL does not return nested data. You have to format the data yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to fix your array push,  change

```
 array_push($resultArray, $row);
```

To

```
 $resultArray[$row['root_class_name']]['branch_class_name'][] = $row['branch_class_name'];
```

It's not quite your output because your array is a number, but a simple `foreach` can reset that array to what you want.

Comment: Or `$resultArray = array_values($resultArray);` to re-index.

Comment: Poster is not looking to 'reindex', Poster is looking to merge matching rows together.

Comment: I know I was commenting on _but a simple foreach can reset that array to what you want._

Comment: Much thanks! I wasn't sure how to use the foreach, because the format was missing the key for root_class_name and I wasn't just how to add it. I think I just need to understand the foreach/array manipulation in the future.

'$resultArray[$row[$rootClass]][] = $row[$branchClass];'
Can anyone explain how this works, and how keys,values and array depth can be managed - or point me in a direction?

Comment: `$resultArray[$row[$rootClassname]][]` this creates an array of *rootclass* the [] pushes it on the end of the array.   so you will have an array of PA_250x500_block with two entries [0] = PA_250x500_Tblock  and [1] = PA_250x500_StraightBlock, it's close to what you want but the array titles won't be there.  That's why I said a foreach loop will allow you to create a new row with the titles intact